# System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, plugins, dynamics-crm

I have created a WCF Service and deployed it in Azure. I am trying to access that service in Plugin (I have registered that plugin in CRM 2016 environment). Before I test this in plugin, i have already tested in Console App and is working fine.

But When I am trying to access that service in Plugin it is throwing me the below error.

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.
```

I am on .NET framework 4.6.2

I have tried:

- downgrading the project from 4.6.2 to 4.6.1 and
  rebuilt,
- downgrading the project from 4.6.2 to 4.6 and rebuilt,
- downgrading the project from 4.6.2 to 4.5 and rebuilt,
- downgrading the project from 4.6.2 to 4.5.2 and rebuilt.

But none of them worked for me.

Comment: Can you supply Code or Exception-Stack to better can understand the issue?

Comment: Thinking about the issue makes me think the Azure -Configuration could be the source. Do you target 4.6+ on Azure?